# PL\SQL inserting procedure with %rowtype parametr

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, rowtype

I have two tables. I need to do a procedure that inserts a record or records into a table, depending on whether or not the table already exists.
1. The procedure only works if the person with the pin is already in the person table
2. for variant when i need to add record with new person and corresponding entry in stay_person table, nothing happens
3. When commenting on the% rowtype parameter and changing the body accordingly, the procedure for the first case stops working, and for the second case it works fine.

```
--CREATE TABLE PERSON
CREATE TABLE PERSON
   ("P_ID" INTEGER CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON PRIMARY KEY, 
    "P_NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,  
    "P_NAME2" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    "P_PIN" VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT "LENGTH_PIN" CHECK (LENGTH(P_PIN) = 11),
     CONSTRAINT "IS_DIGIT_PIN" CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(P_PIN, '^[0-9]*$'))
     );
--CREATE INDEX
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_PERSON_PIN ON PERSON(P_PIN);
--CREATING SEQUENCE 
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_PERSON START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE NOCACHE;
COMMIT;
/
--CREATE TABLE STAY_PERSON
CREATE TABLE STAY_PERSON
   ("PS_ID" INTEGER CONSTRAINT PK_STAY_PERSON PRIMARY KEY, 
    "PS_P_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    "PS_DATE_START" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    "PS_DATE_STOP" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_PERSON" FOREIGN KEY(PS_P_ID) REFERENCES PERSON(P_ID),
    CONSTRAINT CK_DATE_START_STOP CHECK (PS_DATE_START <= PS_DATE_STOP)  
     );  
--CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX I_STAY_PERSON_DATAE_START ON STAY_PERSON(PS_DATE_START);
CREATE INDEX I_STAY_PERSON_DATAE_STOP ON STAY_PERSON(PS_DATE_STOP);
--CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_STAY_PERSON START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE NOCACHE;
-- //

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_TO_STAY_PERSON(
  NAME2 IN VARCHAR2, NAME IN VARCHAR2, PIN IN VARCHAR2, DATA_START IN DATE, DATA_SOP IN DATE
) AS
  V_PERSON INTEGER;
  V_P_ID PERSON%ROWTYPE;
  V_CURRVAL_P_ID INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO V_PERSON
  FROM PERSON
  WHERE P_PIN = PIN;

  SELECT *
  INTO V_P_ID
  FROM PERSON
  WHERE P_PIN = PIN;

  IF V_Person = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO Person (P_ID, P_NAME, P_NAME2, P_Pin)
    VALUES(SEQ_PERSON.NEXTVAL, NAME, NAME2, Pin);

    V_CURRVAL_P_ID :=SEQ_PERSON.CURRVAL;

    INSERT INTO STAY_PERSON (PS_ID, PS_P_ID, PS_DATE_START, PS_DATE_STOP)
    VALUES(SEQ_STAY_PERSON.NEXTVAL, V_CURRVAL_P_ID, Data_Start, Data_Sop);
    COMMIT;
  END IF;

  IF V_PERSON = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO STAY_PERSON (PS_ID, PS_P_ID, PS_DATE_START, PS_DATE_STOP)
    VALUES(SEQ_STAY_PERSON.NEXTVAL, V_P_ID.P_ID, Data_Start, Data_Sop);
  COMMIT;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
END ADD_TO_STAY_PERSON;
--//

--INSERT FIRET SAMPLE DATA
    INSERT INTO Person (P_ID, P_NAME, P_NAME2, P_Pin)
    VALUES(SEQ_PERSON.NEXTVAL, 'DOE', 'JOHN', '00000000001');

    INSERT INTO STAY_PERSON (PS_ID, PS_P_ID, PS_DATE_START, PS_DATE_STOP)
    VALUES(SEQ_STAY_PERSON.NEXTVAL, 1, SYSDATE-100, SYSDATE-90);
COMMIT;

-- TRY ADD NEW RECORD TO TABLE STAY_PERSON WITH NEW PERSON - FAILED
CALL ADD_TO_STAY_PERSON('DOE', 'JANE', '00000000002', SYSDATE-100, SYSDATE-90);

-- ADD NEW RECORD TO TABLE STAY_PERSON WITH OLD PERSON - OK
CALL ADD_TO_STAY_PERSON('DOE', 'JANE', '00000000001', SYSDATE-85, SYSDATE-70);
```

Comment: Your code looks like a MERGE to me, you don't need PLSQL for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception when the person is not present.

```
declare
   V_P_ID PERSON%ROWTYPE;
begin
   SELECT *
   INTO V_P_ID
   FROM PERSON
   WHERE P_PIN = PIN;

   -- Do something because person is in table
exception
  when no_data_found then
    -- Do something because person is not present in table.
end;
```